# How to catch which event hides my datepicker?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 5 step booking page. First page is to select the resource and quantity. It shows up the **Next** button and an `datepicker` is rendered. I can select the date and it shows up my second button **Next** to proceed. The problem is *if i click anywhere on the DOM* my `datepicker` sets to **display: none;** without specifying to do that anywhere in my code. How can i catch which event is causing that? How can i track what exactly sets display: none; to my `datepicker` ?

Answer (score 2):

the chrome debug tools (right click, inspect, or [F12]) have a *break on* functionnality. I think if you break on attribute modification, you'll be able to inspect the call stack and find what is going on.

[image]